# Drupal 7, How to change pager limit?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to change the default limit of pagers in Drupal 7.
I've done some research, but without succes.

I know that I have to do it in the theme's template.php but don't know how.

Is this comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager/6#comment-693 they show a way to alter the pager, but when I add this to my template.php, I get several errors like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: < in theme_pager_previous() (regel 489 van /home/vhosts/rolandkedde.nl/subdomains/webshop/httpdocs/includes/pager.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: n in theme_pager_next() (regel 528 van /home/vhosts/rolandkedde.nl/subdomains/webshop/httpdocs/includes/pager.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: n in theme_pager_next() (regel 528 van /home/vhosts/rolandkedde.nl/subdomains/webshop/httpdocs/includes/pager.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: n in theme_pager_next() (regel 529 van /home/vhosts/rolandkedde.nl/subdomains/webshop/httpdocs/includes/pager.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: n in theme_pager_next() (regel 531 van /home/vhosts/rolandkedde.nl/subdomains/webshop/httpdocs/includes/pager.inc).
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_get_query_parameters() must be an array, string given, called in /home/vhosts/rolandkedde.nl/subdomains/webshop/httpdocs/sites/all/themes/tao/template.php on line 402 and defined in drupal_get_query_parameters() (regel 408 van /home/vhosts/rolandkedde.nl/subdomains/webshop/httpdocs/includes/common.inc).
```

I hope you guys can tell me a way how to do/fix this.

PS. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drupal 7**

Seems like for Drupal 7 the only way to change the limit is to set it in your query.

For example:

```
// Select nid from published nodes with 20 pager limit 
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->limit(20)
    ->fields('n', array('nid'));

$results = $query->execute();
```

**Drupal 6**

Just copy the default [`theme_pager()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager/6#comment-693) function into your `template.php` file with the name `yourthemename_pager()` where `yourthemename` is the name of your theme and change the `$limit` argument to number you need.

Example with limit to 20:

```
// In your case theme's name is "tao"
function tao_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 20, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 9) {
    global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;
    // all code of function
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Hmz.. The differece between the drupal 6 en 7 functions are:

7.3  tao_pager($vars)
6.3  tao_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 9)

So in Drupal 6 I can change the $limit, but in Drupal 7 I can't do that.

Comment: Hm ... my apologies, didn't pay attention to that I wrote answer for Drupal 6. I'll let you know if I'll find decision for D7.